# video Image processing , how can i?

Tags: java, php, matlab, image-processing, imagej

So Here is the situation.

I have a video that contain some objects that moves (contract to be more accurate),
I'm trying to write a code to calculate these movements in matter of

Frequency of movements (how many contractions per minute)
How far does the contraction goes in mm.

How can this be done ?? :D!
I use Matlab now to to blot amplitude difference between each frame but its not giving very nice results so far.. (very buggy)

Any tips ? language i should use best, or is there already something exist that can compare different images and plot difference ?

Thanks

Comment: What's so funny with the question of how it can be done that it needs such a big grin?

Comment: Why on earth would you like to do image processing in PHP?

Comment: what do you use to measure distances? Markers/features tracking? Region recognition? Raw difference between images?

Comment: @ its for medical prurpose. need measure distance to know how strong was the contraction and compare, i'm using matlab raw difference now but its not sensitive enought

Answer (score 2):

You should try [Processing](http://processing.org) using one of [these libraries](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/#computer_vision).

Keywords to search for: Blob detection, Computer Vision

The best library for tracking moving objects is OpenCV, which can be used from within Processing, too. Tracking faces for example works like a charm there, but for more abstract shapes you should try another library like BlobDetection!

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com) is a great library if you plan to write into C/C++ (or wrapped into [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) if you prefer Java). Matlab is a great tool too, especially if you are working on a proof of concept you may want to work with something more friendly and "lighthearted" than C.

If you plan to measure positions or distances I suggest you to use some calibration toolbox to consider intrinsic/extrinsic parameters and eventually camera defects, it will give you more precise results. It is builtin into OpenCV, or take a look [here](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/) if you plan to use Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

so i'm not expert on this but if you want write something in php you probably would use gd library or imagemagick library also imagemagick utility on linux contains some comparing tool according this http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php